# API Manager 1.6.0: click on WSDL info in Publisher throws an error

Tags: wso2

With the API Manager I have published a service (as user admin) in the /publisher. The on the overview screen there is a WSDL info. Clicking on this WSDL info link, throws an error. Note: The created service (endpoint) is working:

```
<am:fault>
  <am:code>404</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Not Found</am:message>
  <am:description>The requested resource (//registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--KIMHelloWorld21.0.wsdl) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
```

What could be wrong?

Server: Single node
AM Version: 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working, after restarting the API Manager server, the WSDL could be downloaded and viewed.